# can we create two session factory of same database with different users in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate

I am new to spring boot and I  need to use same postgreSQL sql database with two different users in same package in same class

please suggest me the ways which I can do to make it work in my application

I have tried creating two configuration classes and calling session factory in the service class

these are the two configurtion classes

1: Mastercongig file

```
package com.demo.config;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterSessionFactory", transactionManagerRef 
= "masterPostgrsTransactionManager", basePackages = {
    "com.demo.*" })
public class MasterPostgreSqlConfig {

/*
 * @Autowired private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
 */

@Value("${spring.database.driverClassName}")
private String driverClassName;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String dataSourceUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String dataSourceUserName;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String dataSourcePassword;

@Value("${spring.jpa.database-platform}")
private String hibernateDialect;

@Bean(name = "masterPostgrsEntityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterSessionFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(masterPostgresqlDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.demo.entity" });
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
    properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", 
    SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", 
    SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", false);

    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
}

@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource masterPostgresqlDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource masterdataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    masterdataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    masterdataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
    masterdataSource.setUsername(dataSourceUserName);
    masterdataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePassword);
    return masterdataSource;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "masterPostgrsTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager masterPostgresTransactionManagerFactory() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(masterSessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

/*
 * @Bean public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
 * if(entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)== null){ throw new
 * NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory"); } return
 * entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class); }
 */

@Bean(name = "masterSessionFactory")
public SessionFactory masterSessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
    return hemf.getSessionFactory();
}
```

}

2 common config file and i made it as primary

```
package com.demo.config;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "commonSessionFactory", transactionManagerRef 
= "commonPostgrsTransactionManager", basePackages = {
    "com.demo" })
public class CommonPostgreSqlConfig {

/*
 * @Autowired private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
 */

@Value("${common.connection.driver_class}")
private String driverClassName;

@Value("${common.connection.url}")
private String dataSourceUrl;

@Value("${common.connection.username}")
private String dataSourceUserName;

@Value("${common.connection.password}")
private String dataSourcePassword;

@Value("${spring.jpa.database-platform}")
private String hibernateDialect;

@Bean(name = "commonPostgrsEntityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean commonSessionFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(commonPostgresqlDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.demo.entity" });
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
    properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", 
    SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", 
    SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", false);

    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
}

@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource commonPostgresqlDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(dataSourceUserName);
    dataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePassword);
    return dataSource;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "commonPostgrsTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager commonPostgresTransactionManagerFactory() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(commonSessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory commonSessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
    return hemf.getSessionFactory();
}
```

}

i am trying to create session factory object in my class level  like this

```
@Autowired
@Setter
private SessionFactory commonSessionFactory;

@Autowired
@Setter
private SessionFactory masterSessionFactory;
```

getting this error

Description:

Field session in com.demo.dao.impl.democlass required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: Why do you need this? What is your use case?

Comment: like i am using the two sessions in my class in  for some methods i am using common session and for some methods i am using master session

Comment: But why? Why have 2 session factories if they point to the same database, schema etc. So again why do you need this.